# M/M/m Queue birth and death parameters

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I would like to determine $\theta_k$ for a $M/M/2$ system. I understand that $\theta_0 = 1$. I also believe that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda$, and $\mu_1 = \mu$, and $\mu_2 = 2\mu$. Therefore, I think $$\theta_1 = \frac{\lambda}{\mu},\theta_2 = \frac{\lambda^2}{2\mu^2}.\tag{1}$$
However, some solutions I have claim that
$$\theta_k = 2\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k\tag{2}$$
Moreover, from what I understand, the text provides the general case for $M/M/m$,
$$\theta_k = \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^k,\tag{3}$$
for $k = 0,1,\dotsc,m$.
It appears that my answer agrees with the book, but that does not mean I am applying it correctly. Some help sorting this out would be appreciated.

Comment: You are mentioning a text or a book: may I suggest to add a reference?

Comment: Or instead of a reference, it is better to add definitions. Like $\lambda$ is birth rate, $\mu$ is death rate, $\theta$ is exactly what?

Comment: $\theta_j = \prod_{i=1}^j\frac{\lambda_{i-1}}{\mu_i}$ for $j\geq 1$.

Comment: OK I have glossed over the relevant parts of chapter 9 of that book now, and I am afraid that I can only agree with you. So can you provide a reference for the other source with the 2 in the numerator?

Comment: A solution manual, no justification was given.

Comment: Let's put it down to a typo then. If $\lambda<\mu$ but close to $\mu$ there is no way that the steady state will have a higher occupation in bubble 2 than in bubble 1.

Comment: Yeah, I am inclined to agree. It would not be the first time it is wrong. Haha. Ok, thanks!